# How to write a struct with nested recursive data in golang

Tags: arrays, go, go-map, go-structtag

I have data like following

```
{
    "cars": {
        "toyota": [
            "sedan",
            "pickup"
        ],
        "honda": [
            "sedan",
            "couple",
            "pickup"
        ]
                ....
    }
}
```

The list might continue grow. I am trying to find out a proper struct to server the data and return to A http responsewriter.

the struct that I had.

```
type Autos struct {
    Cars struct {
        Toyota []string `json:"toyota"`
        Honda  []string `json:"honda"`
    } `json:"cars"`
}
```

But the above struct has predefined "Toyota" "Honda"

I am looking for a way to only use one or two struct to represent the data structure. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I Unmarshal Dynamic Viper or JSON keys as part of struct field in go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50749869/), [golang struct for json with arbitrary keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15817720/), ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```golang
type Autos struct {
    Cars map[string][]string `json:"cars"`
}
```

Here's a full working example, that prints "coupe":

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
)

type Autos struct {
    Cars map[string][]string `json:"cars"`
}

func main() {
    x := `{
    "cars": {
        "toyota": [
            "sedan",
            "pickup"
        ],
        "honda": [
            "sedan",
            "coupe",
            "pickup"
        ]
    }
}`

    var a Autos
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(x), &a)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    println(a.Cars["honda"][1])
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/2MRkOFvyiks)

Comment: Thanks @Amit Kumar Gupta